# Setting a breakpoint in Xcode causes cursor to go to random line

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Whenever i set a breakpoint in Xcode, using the gutter, my cursor jumps to a random line of code, typically, 10-20 lines above the breakpoint. Why is it doing this? It is very annoying...
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically happens when you turn on various optimizations in your debug build. Debug builds should have *no* optimization. I have [a list of possible causes here](http://joshua.nozzi.name/2010/09/buggered-debugger/). They reduce to making sure:

- "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" is unchecked.
- "Generate Debug Symbols" is checked.
- "Optimization Level" is set to "None [-O0]".
- "Use Separate Strip" is unchecked.
- "Additional Strip Flags" has nothing set (I don’t think this matters if strip isn't run).
- "Unroll Loops" is unchecked
- None of the individual files have optimization-related (like -funroll_loops) flags attached.

More detail is provided in my post.

Comment: I didn't realize how many people have problems with this until I posted two articles after pulling my hair out over a few -funroll_loops flags I forgot I set for a few of my computational classes. :-}

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's jumping cause of compiler optimizations (cursor position follows relative code instruction) in binary. Try building your project without optimizations and try debugging again.

Since i'm not a guru at this yet. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the debugger configuration mentioned above and still get the jumping effect. What I have found works is opening up all my collapsed code (methods, code blocks, and comment blocks) and the problem of the jumping cursor on setting breakpoints goes away.  The shortcut to open collapsed code is ctrl + cmd + down arrow. Unfortunately, the comment blocks you have to do one at a time.  I think this is a pain and almost would rather just deal with the jumping of the breakpoints than opening up my collapsed code.